# Air native sound extension for IOS

Tags: apache-flex, air, air-native-extension

Does anyone know of a sound library for IOS that has been ported to work with Air applications?
I was looking at his list: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html  and did not see anything related to sound but hoping I can find something out there thats not on the list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can check this one: https://github.com/mateuszmackowiak/SoundExtension
This library enables you to control the default player (pause, play and others) and volume.

Answer (score 0):

http://extensionsforair.com/
You can find the extensions here, if not available request one from 'em they will help.

Follow steps in this will be able to make your own pretty soon....

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/transferring-data-ane-ios-pt1.html

Comment: http://sleepydesign.blogspot.in/2012/07/ane-free-air-native-extensions.html
plenty of free ones available here...